# Registration constraint for duplicate users in a web site

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have created the following sql statement in order to check if a user already exists in the database and if so to prevent his registration. However, I have done something wrong because now every registration even from not duplicate users is denied.

```
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = '{$_POST['email']}' OR Fullname = '{$_POST['fullname']}'");

if (count($res) > 0) { 
     echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('User already exists!');window.location.href = '/Register.php';</script>";
     exit; 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can read in the manual, [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

> will return a [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object.

You can use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to properly do this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = '{$_POST['email']}' OR Fullname = '{$_POST['fullname']}'");
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row_count > 0) {
    //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent duplicate users, then use constraints or unique indexes (really the same thing):

```
create unique index users_email on users(email);
create unique index users_fullname on users(fullname);
```

This will prevent duplicates from going into these fields at the database level.  Much safer than trying to do this at the application level.